# App get Crash when press Save Button

Tags: android, button, save, volume

i have an issue regarding saving the volume changed when i press a button, and do not understand why. Could you please help pls? My code Below:

```
    private AudioManager aManager;
    private SeekBar seekVolume;
    private Button save;



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        aManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        Button save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save);

}
    public void saveOnClickListener(View view){

            int progress = 1;
            int keyCode = 0;
            KeyEvent keyEvent;
                aManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, progress  , AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI + AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);
                if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN || keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP){
    seekVolume.setProgress(aManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING));

            }else if (keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN || keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP){
                seekVolume.setProgress(aManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION));

                }
 }

}
```

First i want to make changes for Ringer Volume, and when press Save Button , to commit the changes. Thanks guys

Comment: What does the LogCat say?

Comment: I supose that this doesen't need any permision, isn't it?

Comment: SeekBar seekVolume = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekVolume);

Comment: Don't know if this causes a crash, but you declare it twice. It's enough in onCreate

Comment: add break statement after switch case block.and also remove duplicate declaration of seekVolume.

Comment: W/dalvikvm(420): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
E/AndroidRuntime(420): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(420): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
E/AndroidRuntime(420):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2144)
E/AndroidRuntime(420):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
E/AndroidRuntime(420):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
E/AndroidRuntime(420):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
E/AndroidRuntime(420):at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)

Comment: droidRuntime(420):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(420): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
E/AndroidRuntime(420):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(420):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
E/AndroidRuntime(420):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2139)
E/AndroidRuntime(420): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(420):  at com.save.android.SaveActivity.saveOnClickListener(SaveActivity.java:42)

Comment: THANKS GUYS, Now my app doesn't Crash. But another Problem occured: when i move on seekBar, and than press Save Button, the Ringer Volume pop-up appears, but never change . I think that i do not use progress, or change progress properly. Any ideas pls?

Answer (score 1):

i think in xml u have not add this as u have used method **saveOnClickListener**  add in xml in Button property as

```
 android:onClick="saveOnClickListener"
```

or either u can use in activity as shown below if u have not added in xml

```
 Button save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save);    
 save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          // do here what u want onclick of save button 
               }
        }


    });
```

Comment: In my XML for the save Button, i have `android:onCLick="saveOnClickListener"` Thanks Khan

Comment: now it's working, but see  (see edited code above), and another Comment of mine. Thnks Mate

Comment: for that u have to use seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener().....etc u do this where u get method to imported from which change volume in onProgessChangemethod

Comment: But how can I use `seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener()` inside of `save.saveOnClickListener(View view)` ?

Comment: i don't have enough reputation to talk on chat :|. I try to figure how can i put `seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener()`, out of onCLick, and still , the changes is saved when i press save button

Comment: Still, is the message who alerts me that i must have 20 reputation to talk there :|

Comment: I see the welcome message from you, but cannot reply, because i have this message **You must have 20 reputation on Stack Overflow to talk here. See the faq.**

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12430/discussion-between-ionutz-staniu-and-khan)

Answer (score 0):

you have made the aManager local in oncrete so it's global variable with same name would still null in saveOnClickListener

instead of this

```
 AudioManager aManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
```

use

```
aManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
```

in Oncreate...........

Answer (score 0):

You better make aManager and seekVolume global and remove

```
    SeekBar seekVolume = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekVolume);
```

in the onClickListener